# Can't Open a File or Take Ownership - Access is Denied

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ownership

I can't open a certain exe in Windows 10. It's not a system folder. It was a downloaded game in WindowsApps. I take ownership from the folder of the game folder, but can't take ownership to files inside.

I tried by the normal way:

[image]

I tried `Icacls` by cmd and powershell and got this output:

> Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

I tried `TakeOwn` by cmd and powershell and got this error:

> Access is denied

I don't know more what to do to take program exe ownership

Comment: Did you get the game from Windows Store?  Otherwise the download should not be going to WindowsApps.  Maybe download to a neutral folder.

Comment: The command is `icacls`, you've misspelled it in the question. Perhaps you misspelled it while using the command as well? If `Icacls` doesn't work, maybe try using this format: `takeown /f <filename> && icacls <filename> /grant administrators:F`

Comment: It's from Windows Store. I wrote here wrong, I tried Icacls and the results is "Acces is Denies / Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files" and I also tried takeown resulting in "Access is denied"